# How to call a function passed to Button class as parameter on button click in p5.js?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, html5-canvas, p5.js

Here's my Button class:

```
class Button {
    constructor(x, y, width, height, color, msg, action) {
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
        this.width = width
        this.height = height
        this.color = color
        this.msg = msg
        this.action = action
        fill(this.color)
        rect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height)
        textSize(30)
        fill(255)
        noStroke()
        text(this.msg, this.x + this.width / 2 - 30, this.y + this.height / 2 + 10)
        if (mouseX >= this.x && mouseX <= this.x + this.width && mouseY >= this.y && mouseY <= this.y + this.height) {
            stroke(255)
            if (mouseIsPressed)
                //this.action.call() ?
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my new button created:

```
let startBtn = new Button(width/2 - width/4, height/6 + 100, 300, 100, '#404040', 'Start', changeScene(1))
```

My question is how to call `changeScene(1)` on button click in my `class Button {...}` code?

Comment: When creating button change `changeScene(1)` to  `changeScene` (removing the `(1)`) that will mean you pass the function `changeScene` to the button rather than the result of calling the function. Then where you have `//this.action.call() ?` replace with `this.action(1)`. If you only call the function in the constructor dont add it to the object button. Remove `this.action = action` and call directly Ie replace `//this.action.call() ?` with `action(1)` rather than `this.action(1)`

Comment: Ok, I now understand, thank you!